Is it possible to reference an object's linked Armature bones in a material?
I have a model of a mechanical door, with both sliding and rotating parts, that uses procedural Noise Textures to emulate wear streaks on the bearing surfaces. I combined all the moving and stationary mesh parts into a single Object and added an Armature to make it animatable, but discovered that the Noise Textures don't move with the bones, causing the textures to remain stationary while the mesh moves beneath them, thus appearing to slide across the various moving surfaces as the animation plays out.
My first thought on how to fix this is to get a reference to the relevant Armature bones in each material with a Noise Texture and add the position and rotation vectors of the bone to the object vector, but I can't figure out a way to do that. Is it possible? Or is there a different or better solution to this problem?

In the Shader Editor, use the Generated output of the Texture Coordinate instead of the Object output? If the texture is stretched, correct it with the Scale values of the Mapping node...

In the Shader Editor, use the Generated output of the Texture Coordinate instead of the Object output. If the texture is stretched, correct it with the Scale values of the Mapping node.

This was a much simpler solution than I was expecting to have, though it took some finagling to get working. Thank you for pointing it out!
